# Notification disappears then reappears when clicked on?

Tags: android

Hi I have a notifcation set to go off on a specific day and time. Here is my code -

```
private void createPushTimer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Drawing.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 2, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (day == 4) { //5 is thurs
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7, pendingIntent);
    }
    //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Here is the receiving class for the notification -

```
 public void showNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 1);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Drawing!")
        .setContentText("The new drawing has been updated! Check the new numbers!")
        .setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    //mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

It goes off at the appropriate time (9:48 on wednesday for testing purposes) but when notification is clicked on, it appears again at the start of the app. It does disappear for a second but then reemerges. Even though it is the time when clicked on. Is there a better way of doing this or am I missing something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Meant to say past the time of the notification set in the code

Comment: I believe it is because it is still in the same minute when you open the application and hence the notif, add a seconds check too.